# Assign value to a cell via VBA without changing any format

Tags: excel, vba

I have Workbook B as destination file with some values (note the value and format of the selected cell):

[Workbook B before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACLTQ.png)

I need to copy values from Workbook A (source file) to Workbook B:

[Workbook A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG0UP.png)

I use the following function:

```
Private Function SetData(driveList As Workbook, drive As Integer, parameter_id As String, parameter_name As String, parameter_value As String) As Boolean
    
    Dim rangeFound As Range
    Dim firstRangeAddress As String
    
    With driveList.Sheets(drive).Cells
        
        Set rangeFound = .Find(what:=parameter_name, LookIn:=xlValues)
        
        If Not rangeFound Is Nothing Then
            firstRangeAddress = rangeFound.Address
            Do
                If (rangeFound.Offset(0, -1).Value = parameter_id) Then
                    driveList.Sheets(drive).Range(rangeFound.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value = parameter_value
                    SetData = True
                    Exit Function
                Else
                    Set rangeFound = .FindNext(rangeFound)
                End If
            Loop While Not (firstRangeAddress = rangeFound.Address)
        End If
    End With
    
    SetData = False
    
End Function
```

Everything works great except when I pass the string "00:00:01.000" as the `parameter_value`.

Result:

[Workbook B after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmUsy.png)

I would like to copy the values as they are without any formatting by Excel.

I tried working with the .NumberFormat property, but I don't get the desired result.

Comment: Not enough info/data to reproduce, but try setting the `numberformat` property of the destination range to ***text*** (`.NumberFormat="@"` ***before*** you enter the `parameter_value

Comment: It worked.
`.NumberFormat = "@"
.Value = parameter_value
.NumberFormat = "General"`

Comment: Be aware that a side-effect of changing the NumberFormat back to General, as you show in your comment, will be that any subsequent editing of that cell will cause it to become formatted as a time.